# How to get multiple nested values using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On submitting a button I want to get the values of multiple checkboxes where each checkbox have radio buttons. I expect the output will be like if I check 
 checkbox **One** and select its corresponding radio button **L**, checkbox **Two** and select its corresponding radio button **M**, checkbox **Three** and select its corresponding radio button **C** and it is not mandatory to check all the checkboxes, one may leave some checkbox empty. I want to get the selected item and its corresponding values only.
[image]

```js
 var allCheckedItem = []; 
 $.each(jQuery("input[name='teeth']:checked"), 
   function(){ allCheckedItem.push($(this).val()); 
 }); 
 for (var i = 0; i < allCheckedItem.length; i++) 
 { 
  var eachItem = allCheckedItem[i]; 
  console.log(eachItem);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
     <input name='teeth' type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="One" />One
     <span class="teethproblem1">
      <input name='a' type="radio" id="rb1" value="M" />M
      <input name='a' type="radio" id="rb2" value="L" />L
      <input name='a' type="radio" id="rb3" value="C" />C
     </span>
        </li>
        <li>
     <input name='teeth' type="checkbox" id="cb2"  value="Two"/>Two
     <span class="teethproblem2">
      <input name='b' type="radio" id="rb4" value="M" />M
      <input name='b' type="radio" id="rb5" value="L" />L
      <input name='b' type="radio" id="rb6" value="C" />C
     </span>
        </li>
        <li>
     <input name='teeth' type="checkbox" id="cb3"  value="Three"/>Three
     <span class="teethproblem3">
      <input name='c' type="radio" id="rb7" value="M" />M
      <input name='c' type="radio" id="rb8" value="L" />L
      <input name='c' type="radio" id="rb9" value="C" />C
     </span>
        </li>
        <li>
     <input name='teeth' type="checkbox" id="cb4"  value="Four"/>Four
     <span class="teethproblem4">
      <input name='d' type="radio" id="rb10" value="M" />M
      <input name='d' type="radio" id="rb11" value="L" />L
      <input name='d' type="radio" id="rb12" value="C" />C
     </span>
        </li>
        <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE"></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
```

I expect the output should be: One -> M , Two -> C , Three -> L

Comment: Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: I have tried to solve the problem using the following, here I can get the checkbox value but unable to get corresponding radio button value:

 var allCheckedItem = [];
    $.each(jQuery("input[name='teeth']:checked"), function(){            
        allCheckedItem.push($(this).val());
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < allCheckedItem.length; i++) {
     var eachItem = allCheckedItem[i];
     console.log(eachItem);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another variation on the theme:

```js
const getvals=()=>{var coll={};
 $(':radio:checked')
  .each((i,rb)=>
    $(rb).closest('li')
         .find(':checkbox:checked')
         .each((j,cb)=>coll[cb.value]=rb.value)
   )
 console.log(coll);
 return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
     <input name='teeth' type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="One" />One
     <span class="teethproblem1">
      <input name='a' type="radio" id="rb1" value="M" />M
      <input name='a' type="radio" id="rb2" value="L" />L
      <input name='a' type="radio" id="rb3" value="C" />C
     </span>
        </li>
        <li>
     <input name='teeth' type="checkbox" id="cb2"  value="Two"/>Two
     <span class="teethproblem2">
      <input name='b' type="radio" id="rb4" value="M" />M
      <input name='b' type="radio" id="rb5" value="L" />L
      <input name='b' type="radio" id="rb6" value="C" />C
     </span>
        </li>
        <li>
     <input name='teeth' type="checkbox" id="cb3"  value="Three"/>Three
     <span class="teethproblem3">
      <input name='c' type="radio" id="rb7" value="M" />M
      <input name='c' type="radio" id="rb8" value="L" />L
      <input name='c' type="radio" id="rb9" value="C" />C
     </span>
        </li>
        <li>
     <input name='teeth' type="checkbox" id="cb4"  value="Four"/>Four
     <span class="teethproblem4">
      <input name='d' type="radio" id="rb10" value="M" />M
      <input name='d' type="radio" id="rb11" value="L" />L
      <input name='d' type="radio" id="rb12" value="C" />C
     </span>
        </li>
        <li><input type="button" onclick="getvals()" value="SAVE"></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Highly Recommended Reading: [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

One of the biggest problems you'll run into, is example code that only works with the current html.  If you decide to change that html in just about any way, your code stops working (aka [software brittleness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_brittleness)). The following code extensible (meaning adding more checkboxes/radios will be easy to add, probably requiring no code changes), and should be easy to understand. Removing `li` or adding more html won't cause this code to stop working because it doesn't rely on html structure.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-save').on('click', function(e) {
    var $btn = $(e.currentTarget);
    var $form = $btn.closest('form');
    var $pre = $('.debug');
    $pre.text('');
    $form.find('input:not(".ignore-value")').each(function(_,input) {
      var $input = $(input);
      var value = $input.val();
      if ($input.is('[type=checkbox]')) {
        value = $input.prop('checked');
      }
      var name = $input.prop('name');
      $pre.append('name: ' + name + ':' + value + '\n');
      if ($input.hasClass('js-associate-value') && value) {
        var associatedValue = $($input.data('target')).val();
        if (associatedValue) {
          $pre.append(' - ' + associatedValue + '\n');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
     <input name='teeth' type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="One"  class="js-associate-value" data-target="input[name=d]:checked"/>One
     <span class="teethproblem1">
      <input name='a' type="radio" id="rb1" value="M" class="ignore-value"/>M
      <input name='a' type="radio" id="rb2" value="L" class="ignore-value"/>L
      <input name='a' type="radio" id="rb3" value="C" class="ignore-value"/>C
     </span>
        </li>
        <li>
     <input name='teeth' type="checkbox" id="cb2"  value="Two" class="js-associate-value" data-target="input[name=d]:checked"/>Two
     <span class="teethproblem2">
      <input name='b' type="radio" id="rb4" value="M" class="ignore-value"/>M
      <input name='b' type="radio" id="rb5" value="L" class="ignore-value"/>L
      <input name='b' type="radio" id="rb6" value="C" class="ignore-value"/>C
     </span>
        </li>
        <li>
     <input name='teeth' type="checkbox" id="cb3"  value="Three" class="js-associate-value" data-target="input[name=c]:checked"/>Three
     <span class="teethproblem3">
      <input name='c' type="radio" id="rb7" value="M" class="ignore-value"/>M
      <input name='c' type="radio" id="rb8" value="L" class="ignore-value"/>L
      <input name='c' type="radio" id="rb9" value="C" class="ignore-value"/>C
     </span>
        </li>
        <li>
     <input name='teeth' type="checkbox" id="cb4" value="Four" class="js-associate-value" data-target="input[name=d]:checked"/>Four
     <span class="teethproblem4">
      <input name='d' type="radio" id="rb10" value="M" class="ignore-value" />M
      <input name='d' type="radio" id="rb11" value="L" class="ignore-value" />L
      <input name='d' type="radio" id="rb12" value="C" class="ignore-value" />C
     </span>
        </li>
        <li><input class="js-save" type="button" name="submit" value="SAVE"></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
    <pre class='debug'></pre>
```